# Coordinate convergence and norm convergence in finite and infinite spaces.

Tags: normed-spaces, pointwise-convergence

I know how to show that coordinate convergence implies norm convergence in finite euclidian space.

Also I know how how to show that the same thing does not work in infinite space.

For example:

Consider $\ell^2:=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots):\sum_{n\geq 0}x_n^2<\infty\}$ with norm $\Vert(x_1,x_2,\dots)\Vert=\sqrt{\sum_{n\geq 0}x_n^2}$. Now consider two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n^{(k)})$ where $x_n=0$ for all $n$ and $y_n^{(k)}=\mathbb{1}[n=k]$. Notice that we have $(x_n),(y_n^{(k)})\in\ell^2$ for all $k$. Furthermore, $y_n^{(k)}\to x_n$ as $k\to\infty$ since $y_n^{(k)}=0$ whenever k>n. However, for every k, $\Vert (x_n)-(y_n^{(k)})\Vert=1$, so $(y_n^{(k)})$ does not converge to $(x_n)$ in the norm.

Question 1. But I dont understand it. Can someone show what would go wrong in this example if we replace infinite space with finite space. Might be then I could see difference.

Question 2. Does coordinate convergence and so called point-wise convergence the same things?

Comment: If each term in an infinite sum tends to $0$ it does not follow that the entire sum tends to $0$. That is what makes finite dimensional case different from infinite dimensional case. Answer to Q2: YES.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What about exactly the same example in finite space? In infinite space we take the sequence of coordinate axis (yes?). If we do the same thing in finite space...we can not do this because in finite space we have finite coordinate axis and we can not construct this sequence because it has not infinite terms. Is this the case why we can not construct exactly the same example for finite space?

Comment: All your spaces are infinite spaces. Even the real line is an infinite space. You should say 'finite dimensional space'. The distance function in a finite dimensional space is a finite sum.